# Is it possible to request a scientific experiment from a laboratory?

Tags: experiment-design

I have a scientific experiment that I need done to prove a theory of mine. Unfortunately I don't have the resources to perform said experiment like a fully functional laboratory such as Los Alamos National Laboratory would. Is it possible to request an experiment be done by a laboratory like LANL? Would this cost money?

Comment: That depends on (1) how well you know people at the lab, (2) how well your experiment aligns with work they are funded for, and (3) time available on equipment. In general, it will cost money. There are also some opportunities for access through external proposals, e.g. the Office of Science Nanoscience Centers, but that depends on your particular experimental needs and getting through the proposal process.

Comment: Have you thought about collaborating with an experimental lab? If your ideas are important, you might convince them to do an experiment, so you can publish a paper together.

Comment: My theory is aligned with superfluid vacuum theory or SVT. I need to test if a superfluid, such as superfluid helium, has a greater gravitational field than expected when compared with its non superfluid state.